# meaning of 'When it hits'

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read the phrase in [this transcript](https://www.npr.org/2021/11/10/1054255398/spotifys-music-talk-shows-capture-the-magic-of-early-podcasts).

> QUAH: **When it hits**, and it isn't always, these shows capture a little bit of the magic that reminds me of community radio or early podcasting, which I know is a blasphemous thing to say, given the larger context that these programs are all funded by a for-profit corporation trying to market a new product. I won't dispute this point. And, in fact, I believe broader concerns are on Spotify to be of considerable importance.

What does 'When it hits' mean in this context?

Comment: I have flagged this question and your behavior for moderator attention. You are regularly trashing your questions once they have been answered. That is antisocial behavior on this site. Questions and answers are meant to help others in the community, not just you. If you are unhappy with that,. find somewhere else to ask.

Comment: This type of vandalistic behaviour will continue to attract users' attention. Questions cannot be deleted once there is at least one UPVOTED ANSWER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "When it hits ..." means "When these shows hit their target ...". That is, when they are successful at what they are trying to do.

The previous sentence probably says something about "these shows".

The last sentence (about which you ask in [another question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305508/can-i-change-this-sentence-like-this)) makes little sense to me. It might mean Spotify should be paying attention to other things. but I would not bet on it.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: +1 and I'd add to this that it means something like, "When it has it's intended impact..." in particular, an emotional impact. It's a high compliment to say that a TV show or movie or book "*really **hits** you*".